# Flutter PlatformException invalid email format

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm tweaking my app as I go and I added a "full name" field to store in firebase and display on the user profile page. I'm getting the error "PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL, The email address is badly formatted., null)" when registering a new user. From other similar posts, I can't find any naming conventions which has me at a roadblock.

Register.dart:

```
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Full Name'),
                        validator: (val) =>
                            val.isEmpty ? 'Enter a Full Name' : null,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() => fullname = val);
                        }),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Email'),
                        validator: (val) =>
                            val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() => email = val);
                        }),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Password'),
                        obscureText: true,
                        validator: (val) => val.length < 6
                            ? 'Enter a password 6+ chars long'
                            : null,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() => password = val);
                        }),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.blue[400],
                        child: Text(
                          'Register',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            setState(() => loading = true);
                            dynamic result =
                                await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(
                                    fullname, email, password);
                            if (result == null) {
                              setState(() {
                                error = 'please supply a valid email';
                                loading = false;
                              });
                            }
                          }
                        }),
```

auth.dart

```
Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password, String fullname) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're function declaration says that your parameters come in this order `String email, String password, String fullname`, but the way you are using them is in this order `fullname, email, password`. Change

```
await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(fullname, email, password);
```

to

```
await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, fullname);
```

The only issue is a typo.

You could use named parameters, which might make it more obvious when there are issue like this, but I find it to be useful only with function or constructors with a lot of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you need to trim both email and password

Comment: Please add code snippet example of your answer